# Cannot click any icons in left column

Tags: xcode, xcode5.1

My Xcode looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/My6p2.png

My problem is that I can't click any of the icons under the Run/Stop buttons (Folder, etc.)

Is this a simple fix?..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, by upgrading to Xcode 6 beta (I was on Yosemite beta).